# Windows 10 wifi ssid disappears after restart

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

My wifi SSID seems to disappear whenever I restart my Windows 10 PC. The only thing that works to resolve the issue is to reset the network settings. I've tried updating the drivers to the latest version, but not sure what else could be causing the issue. My wifi card is the ASUS PCE-n15

Comment: It seems unlikely the computer could cause the Router SSID to go away. Have you tried updating the Firmware on the Router.  That is the firs thing I would try,

Comment: I'll give it a try. I assumed it was the PC because its the only device that it happens with

Comment: Hello there. By SSID, do you mean you don't see any SSID at all? Also: define restart? If you mean from when you come out of sleep then this changes everything.

Answer (score 0):

updating the router firmware seems to have solved it!

Comment: Hi user3770416.  If John's answer solved your problem, then you should mark his answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely the computer could cause the Router SSID to go away. So now update the Firmware on the Router. That is the first thing I would try, and that should solve your problem